# RemoteIssue is returned with nil values using jira4r soap interface

Tags: ruby, soap, jira

I'm building a jira soap client that will allow me to update Jira issues.

Problem is when I look up an issue using the getIssue() method, a RemoteIssue object is returned but has nil values in all the standard attributes like: key, summary, description, etc.

Here is my simplified code:

> require 'rubygems'
>   require 'jira4r'
>
> host = "http://testjiraserver"
>   user = "hudsonuser"
>   password = "husdonpw"
>   jira = Jira4R::JiraTool.new(2,host)
>   jira.login(user,password)
>   issue = jira.getIssue("BUILD-101")
>   puts issue.key

This returns the value nil, but a RemoteIssue object is returned and has appropriate values in some customfields that allow me to confirm I have returned the correct issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find the root cause.  Restart of Jira solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me also, with JIRA 4.3.2.  A restart of JIRA also solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that restarting Jira may be a little overkill for this situation. (Especially on a production server)

I'm currently having the exact same problem, and even though I get nil objects with Jira4R it is not the case when I try with SOAPUI or even Savon.

A better solution anyone?